# ProgressBar under ActionBar, like the last GMail app update

Tags: android, gmail, progress-bar, user-experience, pull-to-refresh

i would like advices to reproduce the last refresh we can find in the last gmail update under the bar action. Thank you for support.

I guess, i have to use onScroll handler on a ListView via

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisible, int visibleCount, int totalCount)
```

and calculating a ratio to detect top overscroll ?

But how to reproduce the same refresh animation (Dotted line, Repeat on x-axis) ?

Here some screenshots.

---

[image: Normal state]

[image: Pull state]

[image: Refresh state]

Comment: Seems like this question duplicates another one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029256/how-to-implement-swipe-down-to-refresh-like-in-new-gmail-app