# How to implement "Swipe down to refresh" like in new GMail app

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh

Google release the new Gmail app with an alternate way to handle pull down to refresh.

Instead of showing the started hidden row that is pulled down. Gmail displays an animated message overtop of the action bar.

The message includes an animated horizontal line.

Is this a standard feature of the Android SDK? I can't find anything in the action bar API that would do this.

[image]

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Comment: Seems like a combination of a gesture listener on the ListView and a custom view that updates as the user drags farther down the screen.

Comment: I don't get it, this question hasn't been answered in another post... I want THIS api, the Google one, anyone knows where to get it? or how to call it?

Comment: @LuckyMe I have no problem voting to reopen this question. I too would like to know if there is a specific API for the above. The duplicate is a copy of what Facebook/Apple made popular. Not a true Android feel.

Comment: Related blog post also referring to chrisbanes' solution linked above: http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2013/06/googles-first-pull-to-refresh-good.html

Comment: @laalto you are awesome my man. This should be reopened and that link accepted as the answer. I already implemented the other refresh api, but it's very bulky for what it does. Going to try this other library as soon as I can. thanks.

Comment: @LuckyMe there is no API to do this as of now. However, Chris Banes library is the closest thing you will get. I don't know if he based this on GMail's code but he is a developer advocate at Google, so it can be considered a semi-official library..

Comment: Actually, there's the other chrisbanes pulltorefresh library on github: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh . The one linked by @Cornholio is older and deprecated. The blog post above has the correct link.

Comment: The official API does exist now.  I have linked in an a new answer.

Comment: The pull to refresh in gmail has changed, http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Comment: Is there any one help me for this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34268535/android-add-border-image-to-imageview/34272284#34272284

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Chris Banes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh library on GitHub](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) probably offers pull-to-refresh functionality closest to GMail app.

See also: [Juhani Lehtimäki's analysis of GMail pull-to-refresh](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/2013/06/googles-first-pull-to-refresh-good.html).

Comment: Chris Banes' ActionBar-PullToRefresh library is no longer being maintained ? any alternatives ?

Comment: @AnhSirkDasarp You probably mean his Android-PullToRefresh. This (ActionBar-PullToRefresh) is an alternative.

Comment: The pull to refresh in gmail has changed see: http://antonioleiva.com/swiperefreshlayout/

Answer (score 48):

Google has released support for this directly in the SDK.  I am not sure of what version you need to support (that may be an issue).

Check out the official SDK feature info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html

If you are able to use the SDK one, you will be better off, even Chris Banes wrote a [post](https://plus.google.com/103829716466878605055/posts/8wmKAXEGAG2), suggesting the same.

Comment: awesome. thanks for taking the time to add this answer.

Comment: Unfortunately the implementation of SwipeRefreshLayout lacks the possibility of showing a custom message in an ActionBar overlay for the different refreshing states. Also the ProgressBar is displayed under the ActionBar instead of inside (e.g. like in the Google+ App).

Answer (score 10):

try this...it's work for me.

res/layout/activity_main.xml

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.swipetorefresh.MainActivity"
tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

res/layout/fragment_main.xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout           
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/container"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
       tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

   <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

public static class PlaceholderFragment extends ListFragment implements OnRefreshListener {

    private SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout;

    private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 5;
    private int mOffset = 0;

    private ArrayAdapter<String> mListAdapter;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                false);

        // Configure the swipe refresh layout
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setColorScheme(
                R.color.swipe_color_1, R.color.swipe_color_2,
                R.color.swipe_color_3, R.color.swipe_color_4);

        // Put the first batch of countries in the list
        mListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                android.R.id.text1,
                getCountries(mOffset));

        setListAdapter(mListAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

    private List<String> getCountries(int offset) {
        ArrayList<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<LIST_ITEM_COUNT;i++){
            countriesList.add(COUNTRIES[offset+i]);
        }

        mOffset = offset + LIST_ITEM_COUNT;
        return countriesList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {
        // Start showing the refresh animation
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);

        // Simulate a long running activity
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               updateCountries();
            }
        }, 5000);
    }



    private void updateCountries() {

        // Add the next batch of countries to the list
        mListAdapter.addAll(getCountries(mOffset));

        // Signify that we are done refreshing
        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }



    private static final String[] COUNTRIES = {"Afghanistan",
        "Albania", "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola",
        "Anguilla", "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina",
        "Armenia", "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan",
        "Bahamas", "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus",
        "Belgium", "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan",
        "Bolivia", "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil",
        "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
        "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde", "Cayman Islands",
        "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile", "China",
        "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands", "Colombia",
        "Comoros", "Democratic Republic of the Congo (Kinshasa)",
        "Congo, Republic of(Brazzaville)", "Cook Islands", "Costa Rica",
        "Ivory Coast", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus", "Czech Republic",
        "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica", "Dominican Republic",
        "East Timor (Timor-Leste)", "Ecuador", "Egypt",
        "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea", "Estonia", "Ethiopia"};

        }
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Chris Banes ( the same guy who implemented the best pull to refresh component for android) also implemented the `Gmail` like Pull To Refresh.

You can find it here: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh

Note that this project is still under development so the current API may change.

Answer (score 1):

```
fragment_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.testloading.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment" >

  <ListView
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>    


counteries.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>



package com.example.testloading;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private ListView listView;
        private static final int LIST_ITEM_COUNT = 20;
        private int mOffset = 0;
        private boolean flag_loading;

        private MyAdapter adapter;
        private List<String> list;

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,
                    false);

            listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
            list = getCountries(mOffset);
            adapter = new MyAdapter(list, getActivity());
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

                @Override
                public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view,
                        int scrollState) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "firstVisibleItem : " + firstVisibleItem
                            + " , visibleItemCount : " + visibleItemCount
                            + " , totalItemCount : " + totalItemCount);
                    if (firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount == totalItemCount) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "ZZZ offSet : " + mOffset);
                        if (COUNTRIES.length > mOffset) {
                            if (flag_loading == false) {
                                Log.d(TAG, "ZZZ inside : ");
                                flag_loading = true;
                                additems();
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
            return rootView;
        }

        protected void additems() {
            list.addAll(getCountries(mOffset));
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listView.invalidate();
            flag_loading = false;
        }

        private List<String> getCountries(int offset) {
            ArrayList<String> countriesList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < LIST_ITEM_COUNT; i++) {
                if (COUNTRIES.length > offset + i) {
                    countriesList.add(COUNTRIES[offset + i]);
                }
            }

            mOffset = offset + LIST_ITEM_COUNT;
            return countriesList;
        }

        private static final String[] COUNTRIES = { "Afghanistan", "Albania",
                "Algeria", "American Samoa", "Andorra", "Angola", "Anguilla",
                "Antarctica", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Argentina", "Armenia",
                "Aruba", "Australia", "Austria", "Azerbaijan", "Bahamas",
                "Bahrain", "Bangladesh", "Barbados", "Belarus", "Belgium",
                "Belize", "Benin", "Bermuda", "Bhutan", "Bolivia",
                "Bosnia and Herzegovina", "Botswana", "Brazil",
                "Brunei Darussalam", "Bulgaria", "Burkina Faso", "Burundi",
                "Cambodia", "Cameroon", "Canada", "Cape Verde",
                "Cayman Islands", "Central African Republic", "Chad", "Chile",
                "China", "Christmas Island", "Cocos (Keeling) Islands",
                "Colombia", "Comoros",
                "Democratic Republic of the Congo (Kinshasa)",
                "Congo, Republic of(Brazzaville)", "Cook Islands",
                "Costa Rica", "Ivory Coast", "Croatia", "Cuba", "Cyprus",
                "Czech Republic", "Denmark", "Djibouti", "Dominica",
                "Dominican Republic", "East Timor (Timor-Leste)", "Ecuador",
                "Egypt", "El Salvador", "Equatorial Guinea", "Eritrea",
                "Estonia", "Ethiopia" };

    }
}

class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> list;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public MyAdapter(List<String> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.counteries, null);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.textView = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.text_view);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.textView.setText(list.get(position));
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test it.
Using:
swipeRefreshLayout.setRotation(180f);

And in your adapter ListView, method getView:
view.setRotation(180f);

invert order of your items in List.

Or using directly android:rotation="180" in xml.