# Need help on chris bane pull to refresh listview on how to implement load more?

Tags: android, android-listview, pull-to-refresh, android-lazyloading

i am currently using chris bane pull to refresh library and i need the method of the normal listview like ".getFirstVisiblePosition()" and ".setSelection(number)" would anyone know how to get this method and how to implemnt load more???

-thanks

Comment: Hay Check this stack overflow  Link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029256/how-to-implement-swipe-down-to-refresh-like-in-new-gmail-app/21339123#21339123

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chris Banes's ListView has an internal ListView class. You can access it via `getRefreshableView()` method.
For example:

```
((ListView)youListView.getRefreshableView()).getFirstVisiblePosition();
```

Comment: thanks Roman Black for the answer now i can use all of the internal listview methods.