# gmail like Progress bar functionality

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-progressbar, drawerlayout

[image]I am creating a gmail like progress bar functionality. There seems to be some space between the actionbar and the progress bar.

Following is the code

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:indeterminateOnly="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: You use or see sources already developed bars here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17029256/how-to-implement-swipe-down-to-refresh-like-in-new-gmail-app

Comment: I did go through it. But thats the swipe down to refresh functionality. I looked at its implementation as well. But couldn't find anything specific

Comment: I dont understand the space between the progress bar and the action bar. it should ideally start from where the action bar height ends

Comment: Oh, sorry. Understood.

Answer (score 1):

`DrawerLayout` should contain only two children: `FrameLayout` for your content and `fragment` for drawer. Thus `ProgressBar` should be located inside dynamically created content.

Comment: ok, so after putting the progress bar inside the frame layout, I cannot see the progress bar at all

Comment: @androiddeveloper this is another question. So create new one.

Answer (score 0):

To add a `navigation drawer`, declare your user interface with a `DrawerLayout` object as the root view of your layout. Inside the DrawerLayout, add one view that contains the main content for the screen (your primary layout when the drawer is hidden) and another view that contains the contents of the navigation drawer. for more [*`Creating a Navigation Drawer`*](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html).