# Android add border image to ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

Is it possible to add a bitmap as border of an ImageView in android dynamically in Java?

I have already tried the following:

> Image view in XML and border as shape the result is wrong I want to add bitmap in border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You have got multiple options:**

1. Place an other View with the border (also imageview) above your Imageview. Thay might be the simples solution. Just add an other view to your xml and make sure they are overlapping. (Use for example a Relative or FrameLayout as container)
2. Use a [Layer List](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList) and draw a shape above a Bitmap and add that to your ImageView
3. Write a custom ImageView and use the Canvas to draw the Border in the overwritten onDraw method. E.g. canvas.drawRect(...) its pretty straightforward.

Comment: thank for your suggestion... now please tell me is it possible ( I have transparent  image of phone now I want to use it to simple image where that image fit into that transparent  portion ) so its look like that image has phone background.                      https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/app-types-in-grey/512/apps_512pxGREY.png

Comment: you can also check this app's   logo    play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.knt

Comment: @KinjalPatel Yeah well the simples solution might be to make the Screen of your phone image transparent and lay that over your desired background. But there are multiple ways to do that. Maybe you should just  try the one which you like most and open up a new question if you got problems.

Comment: have you checked this app's logo...?                https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.knt

Answer (score 3):

The simple way：

A **drawable** for **ImageView**'s attr that `android:foreground`

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">


    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#ff0000" />

    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>

</shape>
```

Then **XML**,

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/unreserved_head_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/shape_border"
    />
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution I found recently.
Try to use material theme in your app. Use `"Theme.MaterialComponents.Light"`

Then use image view inside and material card view.

```
        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardElevation="0dp"
            app:strokeColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:strokeWidth="1dp">
              
              <ImageView/>//define you image view hear
       
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
```

With property `stokeColor` and `strokeWidth` you can have border on an image view and make it dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

you can use 9 patch in andorid studio to make an image a border!

i was finding a solution but i did not find any so i skipped that part

then i go to the google images of firebase assets and i accidentaly discovered that they use 9patch

[image: 9patch in action]

heres the link: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch
you just need to drag where the edges are

its just like boder edge in unity